# Golang goroutine not running defer with function that uses range on channel

Tags: go

A range on a channel

```
for s := range cs {
    fmt.Println("Recieved Cake: ", s)
}
```

should keep a function open until the channel closes at which point the function/goroutine should terminate. When a function terminates the defer function should run just prior. This doesn't seem to be the case and I can't find any reasons why.

Sample code at http://play.golang.org/p/ADu1MzAe9P produces defer statements as expected except for the function that is recieving from the channel. Any reasons as to why this would be? thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason why the defer function is not executing is that the application reaches the end of the `main` function causing the entire program to terminate without waiting for goroutines.

[Go Specification](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Program_execution) says:

> When the function main returns, the program exits. It does not wait for other (non-main) goroutines to complete.

Since your `recieveCakeAndPack` is still waiting for the channel to close (which never happens) it will never defer before the termination of the program.

**Edit**

On a side note - putting the defer statements last in a function is not meaningful. Instead put them directly after the statement you want to defer such as:

```
fmt.Println("Entering function")
defer fmt.Println("Leaving function")
```

or

```
file, err := os.Open("file.txt")
if err != nil {
    return err
}
defer file.Close()
```

The defer function/method calls will be executed when leaving the function in a Last-In-First-Out order.

Comment: Thanks for the tip about placing defer statements, I had hastily thrown them in last minute to experiment but you are absolutey right about there placement. The main concern I had was that the function never returns (because I never closed the channel!), it seems obvious now that you point it out that either function wouldn't know the length or extent of my data but I was assuming it somehow magically knew. I updated the example with the fixed defers and channel close at http://play.golang.org/p/nuQ2BktQM4 and everything works as I would expect it to. Thanks